# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.setMetadataProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, pom.xml

I get an error when trying to use Configuration.BuildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.setMetadataProvider
```

Here my relevant Hibernate dependencies :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>
        hibernate-validator-annotation-processor
    </artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I can't figure what's going wrong, please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I added the dependency but it did not solve my problem, I'm still getting the same error.